# CDI @Target warning message on Netbeans

Tags: java, cdi, netbeans-7

In my web project using CDI, Netbeans 7.1.2 warns on my custom qualifier

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface MyQualifier{

}
```

with message:

```
The CDI Annotation is declared as Qualifier but it has wrong target values. Correct target values are '{METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE'} or '{FIELD, PARAMETER'}.
```

Yes it is only warning but still I am curious about the meaning of this message. Could not find any good reference on `@Target` in the net. So someone here can give some explanation about the Target and the warning message. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, according to section 2.3.2 of the CDI spec they're both incorrect. A qualifier must be METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE.

Comment: I should to have read the spec first. At least the "{METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE}" is correct, isn't it? But there is no info about "{FIELD, PARAMETER}" part in the spec.

Comment: Correct. Not sure where netbeans is getting that value. Perhaps interpreting that as an Observer only qualifier? But there is no such thing.